# How to concatenate string array in JavaScript - with modification while concatenating

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, for-loop, concatenation

I have an array and want to get those elements in a string.
This is what I have inside a JavaScript function,

```
var main = [X, Y];
    var str = "";    

    for (var i = 0; i < main.length; i++) {

        str = { label: main[i] };               
    }
```

with above code I get the last value stored in the var 'str'
Output I am getting: `str={label: Y}`
Output I want: `str= {label: X}, {label: Y}`

Comment: But `str` is not a string... Maybe you want `join`.

Comment: `str` is a string but you are assigning an Object...

Comment: How do i fix this? Any suggestions/help..really appreciated.

Comment: @user3381574 - First you have to understand the concept of `type` in programming.

Comment: please post the entire function, and give some context of what you are doing and what you want to achieve. [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) will give you something resembling what you're looking for, but your code needs fixing first

Comment: `"{label:" + main.join("},{label:") + "}"` http://jsfiddle.net/S7QC3/

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone. i really appreciate your responses.

Answer (score 0):

```
var main = ["X", "Y"];

var str = main.map(function(n){ return "{label:" + n + "}" }).join(",");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/u49nS/

Your code doesn't work is because you can't add Object to a String. This will cause the browser to cast the object into a String (`[object Object]`):

```
str = { label: main[i] };
```

---

As sean9999 suggested in the comments above, it seems that you are trying to turn Objects into JSON. To do that you do not use a for loop because there is a native way of doing it by using `JSON.stringify`.

```
str = JSON.stringify(main);
```

Comment: Who is downvoting all the answers?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your replies. I am not down voting any of the answer. I tried to vote up all of them but it won't let me since I don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

you want string "X" and "Y" to be put in str += { label: _ }

instead of X and Y use "X" and "Y",and also concatenate them in between as string to "{ label: " and " }"

```
var main = ["X", "Y"];
    var str = "";    

    for (var i = 0; i < main.length; i++) {

        str += "{ label: "+main[i]+" }";               
    }
```

EDIT:
in above post ',' wont be applied

here is code to include that too.

```
var main = ["X", "Y"];
    var str = "";    

    for (var i = 0; i < main.length; i++) {

        str += "{ label: "+main[i]+" }, ";               
    } 
if(str.length){
    str = str.substr(0,str.length-2);
}
alert(str)
```

Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/hLJN6/

Comment: Thanks a much Baljeetsingh for your response. I am trying to fix my code now. It's very helpful.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that each time you go through the loop you are resetting the value of str. You need to do something like

```
str = str + { label: main[i] };
```

Edited to add that I agree with the response that you are dealing with objects here, not strings. But you say that's what you want, so probably a completely different approach is in order.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `[object Object][object Object][object Object]` isn't the expected output.

Comment: Well, it's not a string, but it is what he said he wanted. That's why I edited my answer.